# ASP.NET 4.0 Routing only for Login Page

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to apply Routing only to Login.aspx? Why, because once a user logged into website, they will continue with normal browsing. for eg.

```
www.test.com/01
```

may be 01 is a kind of user, after logged in they can browse to

```
www.test.com/products.aspx
www.test.com/sales.aspx
```

etc.....

Comment: I not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I suppose you may be interested in ASP.NET Froms authentication http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx. Using it, you can use methods redirecting to login page and back when user is not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

i have found an answer

this is my configuration,

```
routes.Ignore("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });<br>
routes.Ignore("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });<br>
routes.Ignore("{*allaxd}", new { allaxd = @".*\.axd(/.*)?" });<br>
routes.MapPageRoute("Routing", "{Id}", "~/Login.aspx");
```